# Using spring-roo 2, how to add an user with spring security

Tags: spring-roo

As configuration and settings are in java, there's no more xml configuration files, it is hard to find tutorials, documents and how-to with this new design. So... basically, how to add an user and his password, where to find the security-configuration "file" of spring-security (like old applicationContext-security.xml)...

Then, I have made a maven clean, and the generate QClasse from my entity disappear, so the application can not compile any more. How to regenerate the QClasses (in target/generated-sources/java) ?

I notice the spring-roo project was created under Eclipse with the J2SE-1.5 library, so it couldn't compile. I had to change the library to JDK1.8. Some errors with wrong overrides methods remains.

Anyway, how to add user with new spring-security configuration please.

I'm using Spring-roo 2.0.0.M3.

Answer (score 0):

First, I advice you to take a look about [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/index.html) as it's the base of Spring Roo generated project. This will explain all about how you can cusmize your project configuration.

In this way, there is the [Spring Boot documentation about Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html) and its [how-to guides](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-change-the-authenticationmanager-and-add-user-accounts). An example class which configures a user is:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("barry").password("password").roles("USER"); // ... etc.
    }

    // ... other stuff for application security

}
```

> Then, I have made a maven clean, and the generate QClasse from my entity disappear, so the application can not compile any more. How to regenerate the QClasses (in target/generated-sources/java) ?

These classes are generated by *apt-maven-plugin* plugin in *compilation* phase. So, simplely execute `mvn clean complile` to generate it.

> I notice the spring-roo project was created under Eclipse with the J2SE-1.5 library, so it couldn't compile. I had to change the library to JDK1.8. Some errors with wrong overrides methods remains

In [Spring Roo Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#getting-started-requirements) explains that Spring Roo requires JDK6 as *minimun* java version. Also, check that maven version is 3.3 or above.

Good luck!